# Весь список стран в SxGeo

Tags: php

Задача в том, что пользователь вводит наименование страны.

Необходимо выполнить поиск стран по ключу который ввел пользователь. То есть отдать пользователю список стран приближенные к его ключу.

При помощи SxGeo, возможно выполнить данную задачу?

Сперва пользователь выбирает страну, затем вводит наименование областей. Необходимо выдать приближенный список областей конкретной страны, а затем город.

Если не возможно, то есть ли бесплатные готовые библиотеки под данную задачу?